# How to bind a label to a field found in the same window class in WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, binding

I have a standard WPF app created using Visual Studio template. My MainWindow code looks like this:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow ( )
    {
        this.InitializeComponent ( );
    }

    string MyValue = "";
}
```

How can I bind my Label to MyValue using XAML?

Comment: You can't, because `MyValue` is a private field and you can only bind to public properties.

Comment: Thanks I changed it to public but I cant figure out the full path I need to use in XAML to have the binding work.

Comment: Show the result you needed.

Comment: You can either set datacontext of window to itself (`this.DataContext = this` before `InitializeComponent` for example), then you can bind as `{Binding MyValue}`. That's not a good thing to do though. Or you can name your window in xaml (`x:Name=myWindow`), then you can bind with `{Binding ElementName=myWindow, Path=MyValue}`.

Comment: What do you mean bind? you want to pass the value of your `MyValue` to a `Label`?

Comment: @Evk it works perfectly thanks.

Comment: @VijunavVastivch yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my .cs file :

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        DataContext = this;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public string MyValue { get; set; } = "Hello";
}
```

and my view file :

```
 <Grid>
    <Label Content="{Binding MyValue}"/>
</Grid>
```